# Integrate elFinder.NetCore in project : [error] The volume root statuses requires `volumeid` property

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-3.1, elfinder

I am trying to integrate the javascript elfinder library into my asp.net 3.1 + angular 9 project, I can launch the example project (https://github.com/gordon-matt/elFinder.NetCore) , it works perfectly but when I integrate everything in my project I get the error "elfinder debug: [warning] [elfinder] The volume root statuses requires `volumeid` property. " it is displayed 10 times then an error 500 appears, I do not understand where it comes from?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :
[image]

the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" create a conflict

Answer (score 0):

It's still possible to use [AddNewtonsoftJson()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.newtonsoftjsonmvccorebuilderextensions.addnewtonsoftjson) in Startup but it means that you'll have to serialize the returned object with [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json) instead using the following code in the controller:

```cs
var result = await connector.ProcessAsync(Request);
if (result is JsonResult)
{
    var json = result as JsonResult;
    return Content(JsonSerializer.Serialize(json.Value), json.ContentType);
}
else
{
    return result;
}
```